# Appending data inside a tableView in the background - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, background

My app works like this - you press an `uibutton` and it starts appending data inside a `tableView` with a specific delay, cell by cell. Sometimes it may take hours to append, because of the manually set delay parameter.

The problem is each time i switch it to background - the app gets suspended after several minutes (up to five usually) and the whole process breaks.

Is there any approach to handling this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: save what time it is whenever app goes to background and then renew all timers when it goes back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the designed behavior, an app return to background normally only have very short active time, then it will be suspended, but there are some exceptions:

1. Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as
2. Music player app
3. Apps that record audio content while in the background
4. Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
5. Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
6. Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
7. Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Basically speaking, if your app need to interact with outside for resource that can not be generated inside your app, you can apply for background running.

Any every app can legally apply a background task to run for a short time when the app enter background mode.

In your case, even if you implemented the background running, your app will possibly be rejected. If your app is doing the adding to table action controlled by a timer, you should be able to simulate the behavior yourself.

1. save a the system time stamp locally, maybe in UserDefault
2. when app launch or enter foreground, get the system time, you can calculate the time difference and figure out how many actions you should take and perform that with a batch action.
3. after that, clear the saved time stamp ensure next time your data won't be messed up.

Comment: Brilliant answer! Just what I needed